# How can I get this result in RegEx using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

1. If my entry is "001.1-2016", I want "001.2-2016"
2. If my entry is "001.8-2015", I want "001.9-2016"
3. If my entry is "001.12-2014", I want "001.13-2016"
4. If my entry is "001.123-2016", I want "001.124-2016"

I tried a regex like this:

```
([0-9]{3}\.)(.*)(\-[0-9]{4})
```

but this get all, I want only the middle.

Comment: how can I get ? I dont wanna the finish "-2016"

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a code writing service. You need to show what you've tried, what when wrong, and how you've approached the issue.

Comment: ok, I tried a regex in sublime: ([0-9]{3}\.)(.*)(\-[0-9]{4})

Comment: Sorry @Tushar, I cant understand "Add that in question"

Comment: I thought something like this: ([0-9]{3}.)       ????     (-[0-9]{4})

Comment: Ok @Oka, I tried a regex in sublime: ([0-9]{3}\.)(.*)(\-[0-9]{4})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your regex [`(\[0-9\]{3}\.)(.*)(\-\[0-9\]{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/oJ6iZ8/2) works fine**, you just need to get the second captured group result.

```js
var arr = ["001.1-2016", "001.8-2015", "001.12-2014", "001.123-2016"];
var regex = /([0-9]{3}\.)(.*)(\-[0-9]{4})/;

arr.forEach(function(str) {
    document.body.innerHTML += str.match(regex)[2] + '<br />';
});
```

---

You can use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
var value = "001.12-2014";
var num = parseInt(value.split('.')[1], 10);
```

```js
var value = "001.12-2014";
var num = parseInt(value.split('.')[1], 10);

document.body.innerHTML = num;
```

Using Regex

```
var value = "001.12-2014";
var num = value.match(/.*?\.(\d+)/)[1];
```

```js
var value = "001.12-2014";
var num = (value.match(/.*?\.(\d+)/) || [])[1];

document.body.innerHTML = num;
```

---

> I need just add +1 in this number, eg. "001.12-2014" >>> "001.13-2014" or "001.123-2014" >>> "001.124-2014"

```js
var arr = ["001.1-2016", "001.8-2015", "001.12-2014", "001.123-2016"];
arr = arr.map(e => e.replace(/\.(\d+)/, ($0, $1) => '.' + (1 + +$1)));

document.body.innerHTML = arr;
```

To increment the number by 1 you can use `String#replace`

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var value = this.value;

    value = value.replace(/\.(\d+)/, function($0, $1) {
        return '.' + (1 + +($1 || 0));
    });

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = value;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, if it is not abusing its goodwill, I need just add +1 in this number, eg. "001.12-2014" >>> "001.13-2014" or "001.123-2014" >>> "001.124-2014";

Comment: @WilliansMartins I've added update at the bottom of answer. I've also added a demo to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

The regex pattern could be

```
/[0-9]+\.([0-9]+)\-[0-9]+/g
```

if you do not concern the number format before `.` and after `-`

You can test it on [here](https://regex101.com/r/gY2dQ3/1).

Comment: thanks a lot, if it is not abusing its goodwill, I need just add +1 in this number, eg. "001.12-2014" >>> "001.13-2014" or "001.123-2014" >>> "001.124-2014"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use split method .The `split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "001.12-2014";
    var res = new Array();
    res=str.split("."); 
    var finalres=res[1].split("-",1);   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = finalres;
}
</script>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, if it is not abusing its goodwill, I need just add +1 in this number, eg. "001.12-2014" >>> "001.13-2014" or "001.123-2014" >>> "001.124-2014"

Comment: It's fine.Glad you got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

this matches all 4 (find the decimal and take one or more digits that follow):

```
/\.(\d+)/g
```

@ https://regex101.com/r/qG2mX7/4

Comment: thanks a lot, if it is not abusing its goodwill, I need just add +1 in this number, eg. "001.12-2014" >>> "001.13-2014" or "001.123-2014" >>> "001.124-2014"

Comment: That's a different problem - you asked for regex find. What you do with it afterward depends on what environment you're in. Some environments (like Perl) have "Replacement Text" but those are string manipulations. If you're still manipulating in JavaScript, you'll just have to add to the result.